# How to checkout a specific commit and save in another folder

Tags: git

I have a git repository on my computer. I want to checkout a specific commit and save it to **another folder that's not a git repository**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use branch:

```
git reflog   # get the sha or reflog shortname  of your desire commit, for example 29b89f9 
git branch branch_name 29b89f9    
git checkout branch_name
```

and than copy all file to a folder `A` and delete the `.git` in folder `A`.

if the branch is no more needed, delete it with:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d branch_name
```

Answer (score 2):

After you have checked out a commit, your working copy will be in the state of that particular commit. All you have to do now is to copy the whole folder over.

One thing to note is this copy will make the destination a git repo as well. You can delete the `.git` folder (hidden folder) in the destination to turn it back to normal folder.

With steps:

1. Lets A be the git repo, B be the destination
2. `git checkout <commit-id>`. This makes A to be the state that you want
3. Copy A to B
4. B is identical to A now. It is also a git repo. To make it not a git repo, delete its `.git` folder
5. You can do whatever you want with A now :)

Comment: And after that I can return to latest commit?

Comment: Yes, then you can do whatever you want with the original git repo. The copied folder is not connected to the original one, especially if you deleted the `.git` folder